# jquery sorting dom elements based on its css("color")

Tags: jquery, css, sorting, colors

What you can see on following page is a list of usernames in some random order. I want to use jquery to sort them in this order:

red
blue
green
purple
black

http://www.arvag.net/test/sorting/

This is what i did so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var admin       = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    var moderator   = "rgb(00, 00, 255)";
    var text        = "rgb(00, 128, 00)";
    var vip         = "rgb(128, 00, 128)";

    var adminBuffer = [];
    var moderatorBuffer = [];
    var textBuffer = [];
    var vipBuffer = [];
    var html;

    $("div#active_users span.name").each(function(i) {
        color = $("a span",this).css("color");
        html = $(this).html();
        if(admin == color){
            adminBuffer[i] = "<span class='name'>" + html + "</span>";
        }
        //$(this).clone().append("&nbsp").appendTo('#rezultat');
    });
    jQuery.each(adminBuffer, function() {
        //alert(this);
        $(this).appendTo("#rezultat");
    });
});
</script>
```

I managed to get a match for the red one, but im simply failing to append it to another element with an id of "rezultat".

Any idea or sugestion is welcome!

Comment: Seems a little inside-out.  I'd have the users in separate classes (admin, moderator, etc..) by type and then order by the classes.   (similar problem). Then apply the right CSS to get the correct colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i added class(admin, moderator, etc) to my elements and now its easy... ;) So thanks clintp for idea... :)

Answer (score 0):

[TinySort](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort) is a plugin to sort child nodes by (sub) contents or attributes. Very useful for ordering unordered lists or tables, but works on any type of node.